# How to place content type settings in Orchard CMS Admin?

Tags: settings, admin, orchardcms

I recently updated Orchard to 1.10.1 and there seems to be a placement issue with some content type part settings:

- *Orchard 1.9*

[image: Drop down with Html above Html flavor settings]

- *Orchard 1.10.1*

[image: Drop down with Html below Html flavor settings]

How can i adjust the placement in a way that my settings (Html flavor settings) will be displayed below the drop down again?

I tried to use shape tracing to create a `Placement.info` file but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find another way to enforce the ordering as the solution of [mdameer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37441972/3936440) does not work and i came up with a simple jQuery solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get fieldset with my settings
    var $HtmlFlavorSettings = $(".html-flavor-settings");

    // get flavour drop down
    var $flavorSelection = $HtmlFlavorSettings.closest("form").find("[name$=\"BodyTypePartSettings.Flavor\"]");

    if ($flavorSelection.length > 0)
    {
        // place fieldset with my settings after fieldset with flavour drop down
        $HtmlFlavorSettings.insertAfter($flavorSelection.closest("fieldset"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Orchard "IContentDefinitionEditorEvents.DefinitionTemplate()" method will return an object of type "TemplateViewModel", so you can return this object directly with defined position from "TypePartEditor()" method, like the following:

```cs
yield return new TemplateViewModel(settings, typeof(settings).Name) {
    TemplateName = "DefinitionTemplates/" + typeof(settings).Name,
    Position = 10
};
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work as a) `Position` is not a numeric type, it's a string and b) i have tested it with `"10"` and other values, i also have changed the source code of `BodySettings.cs` to apply a position but it doesn't work either.